# possible to pull classes and ids using post_content?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

just to explain briefly what Im trying to do, Im building a site for a local football team, on the homepage there are plans for a div with a league table on it, I want the user to able to easily adjust the league table by editing a single post. 
So far my code is this

```
<div class="teaminfo"> <?php
$post_id = 923;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?></div>
```

But in my table i have a various classes applied to the rows, as I want borders and background colours.
I assume that "post_content" is only going to pull literally the content , so im just wondering does anyone know any other way around this? I cant apply classes and divs in the code above because the same thing will be applied to ALL the content in one go if you get me.

Thanks for the help

EDIT: just adding one more thing, the reason Im not just giving the div a background of the colours I want and laying the content over it, is because the sites team will be highlighted a different colour so as they move up or down the table that colour will have to change

Comment: I'm finding it hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here - are you wanting to apply classes to individual table rows so that you can style them? What does the current HTML output look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yea pretty much, Im applying classes to the table rows in my html editor on WP. And when I view this page on its own, those classes work perfectly fine.

BUT, I want those classes to also be applied when I call the content using the code above, so when the content of the page is revealed in a seperate div on its own on the homepage(like a little widget), the classes are there too.

I understand that what Im trying to do wont work with just the code above but Im wondering is there anything else I can include that could help.

Comment: It would be useful to see your HTML as it may be possible to style it with CSS3 selectors - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ - although this would only work with CSS3 enabled browsers. Otherwise I think you will have to dig into Wordpress to format the returned content. I'm not that familiar with Wordpress myself but I believe you will need to look at Wordpress Hooks and Filters to do this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API. Maybe here  http://codegarage.com/blog/2009/05/how-to-display-properly-formatted-content-from-a-post-object-in-wordpress/ ??

Comment: Thanks benedict_w , heres some code..
`<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="lightblue">
<td>Longford Town</td>
<td>7</td>
<td><td>
</tr>
<tr class="darkblue">
<td>Limerick FC </td>
<td>7</td>
<td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lightblue">
<td>Wexford Youths</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr class="lightblue">
<td>Longford Town</td>
<td>7</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`

Im not too fond of the idea of potentially limiting browsers so I think ill have to have a look at the hooks and filters option, or maybe there is a plugin out there that can do something like this already.